# How to force an ASP.NET Web app to use Oracle DLLs in the BIN folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracleclient

So I have an web app that need the Oracle 19c client (4.122.19.1) due to certain syntax changes, while our Dev IIS server has an older 4.121.2.0 client.

Anyway, I put all of what I've heard to be the proper support dlls in the Bin directory of the app, which from all my research are these:
oci.dll
ociw32.dll
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
Oracle.Web.dll
orannzsbb19.dll
oraocci19.dll
oraocci19d.dll
oraociei19.dll
oraons.dll
OraOps19.dll

This runs perfectly from my PC in Visual Studio.   When I deploy to a Dev IIS server (with app-pool running in Enable 32-bit because my PC runs IISExpress in 32-bit)  There are various Oracle connection errors.

Now, in Process Explorer, on my PC, I look at the IISExpress and I can see it's loaded all of the above dlls, though from the GAC because I have this client installed locally.   Yet on the Dev server, Process Explorer, under my W3WP.exe process, I see only the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll and Oracle.Web.dll, but none of the support DLLS.  I'm fairly certain the fact that these are missing, especially OraOps19.dll, is the issue.

I've used the "DLLPath" thing in the web.config, it makes no difference.  I was always told that Asp.Net *always* trys to load from the BIN first.  Yet here I believe it is at least partially ignoring it--both in my PC, which is going straight to the GAC, and from the Dev IIS server, which does get the proper .Web and .ManagedDataAccess from Bin, but nothing else.

How can I make this forget the Gac and force it to find anything it needs Oracle-wise in the Bin?
Thanks

Comment: In Visual studio, when you right click on the DLL under References, what is the value of "Copy Local"? Also, you have the option to set "Specific Version" to True and then set "Version" to the exact one you need. Maybe worth giving it a try..

Answer (score 1):

The dlls are bugged; it's not allowed to release breaking changes to signed dlls like that. Workaround:

Assuming these are 100% il code (no C++/clr involved)

1. ildasm the oracle dlls to .il and .res files
2. Remove all references to the public key
3. ilasm the .il and .res files back to dlls
4. link your application against those dlls

Now it doesn't look in the GAC anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I'm so far down a wormhole with this now.  The ilasm worked fine for the Oracle.web.dll .res and .IL files, but failed on the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll files.  I can't go much further down this abyss.  I think (honestly) I would be time-ahead if I migrated the database to Sql-Server.  I've never had any issues whatsoever with .Net projects when Sql-server is used.  I don't know why Oracle has to be so obscenely complex.  Well, I do know why--Oracle's consultants need to get paid.

Comment: @jimo3: It's a streight-up oracle bug. Your fastest path is to ship an entire VM though.